# Parent div copy dimensions of child image

Tags: html, css, image, position

I need to set my parent div in the way, that it's child image will be inside of it, since parent div has visible border, which have to wrap around image and text. Thank you for any tips :)

[image: My situation]

HTML:

```css
.about-us {
  border: 1.5px solid $grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 275px; //I need to get rid of this as now it's fixed
  .us-image {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      padding: .7%;
    }
  }
  .about-us-text {
    float: left;
    width: 64%;
    margin: 0 3%;
    h3 {
      margin-top: 5%!important;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 130%;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="about-us">
  <div class="us-image">
    <img src="img/about-us.png" alt="about-us">
  </div>
  <div class="about-us-text">
    <h3>Abc</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec pharetra mauris ornare ultricies malesuada. Donec pretium, dolor a dapibus tempor, nisl enim lacinia risus, eget ullamcorper diam velit id tortor. Nulla velit purus, euismod a suscipit
      sed, gravida et ligula. Quisque scelerisque sodales faucibus. Vestibulum ullamcorper eget dui id laoreet. Nullam pellentesque neque sagittis, ullamcorper sem sed, vehicula ex. Nullam lobortis et nibh eget cursus. Aenean vitae blandit lacus.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- /about-us-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the height from `.about-us`div and clear the floats using `clear:both` with `.about-us::after`

html:

```
<section class="about-us">
        <div class="us-image">
            <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/af/99/5d/af995d61b255bfd53bbdbfa343451949.jpg" alt="about-us">
        </div>
        <div class="about-us-text">
            <h3>Abc</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec pharetra mauris ornare ultricies malesuada. Donec pretium, dolor a dapibus tempor, nisl enim lacinia risus, eget ullamcorper diam velit id tortor. Nulla velit purus, euismod a suscipit sed, gravida et ligula. Quisque scelerisque sodales faucibus. Vestibulum ullamcorper eget dui id laoreet. Nullam pellentesque neque sagittis, ullamcorper sem sed, vehicula ex. Nullam lobortis et nibh eget cursus. Aenean vitae blanditd lacus. 
            </p>
        </div>
    </section><!-- /about-us-->
```

css:

```
 .about-us {
border: 1.5px solid black; 
width: 100%;
 //I need to get rid of this as now it's fixed

.us-image {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
        img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            padding: .7%;
         }
 }

.about-us-text {
    float: left;
    width: 64%;
    margin: 0 3%;

    h3 {
        margin-top: 5%!important;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 130%;
        font-weight: 500;
    }

}
}

.about-us::after{
  content: "";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the height and width for the div and set max-width, max height size to 100%. It will auto-fit according to the height and width of the div.

```
.us-image{
    height: 75px;
        width: 75px;
    }
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just added `display: inline-flex;` to your `about-us` class and no need to change anything else in your scss. I just compiled your scss to css.

```css
.about-us {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1.5px solid #000000; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 265px;
}
.about-us .us-image {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  display: inherit;
}
.about-us .us-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: .7%;
}

.about-us-text {
  float: left;
  width: 64%;
  margin: 0 3%;
}
.about-us-text h3 {
  margin-top: 5%!important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 130%;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<section class="about-us">
  <div class="us-image">
    <img src="http://freebigpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/forest-land.jpg" alt="about-us">
  </div>
  <div class="about-us-text">
    <h3>Abc</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec pharetra mauris ornare ultricies malesuada. Donec pretium, dolor a dapibus tempor, nisl enim lacinia risus, eget ullamcorper diam velit id tortor. Nulla velit purus, euismod a suscipit sed, gravida et ligula. Quisque scelerisque sodales faucibus. Vestibulum ullamcorper eget dui id laoreet. Nullam pellentesque neque sagittis, ullamcorper sem sed, vehicula ex. Nullam lobortis et nibh eget cursus. Aenean vitae blandit lacus. 
    </p>
  </div>
</section><!-- /about-us-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Float your image to the left, and add the `overflow:hidden` property to to your parent DIV, also remove fixed height of your DIV.

Answer (score 0):

```
.us-image img{
width:100%;}
```

add this to css